# What is the difference between 'or' and '|' when programming in xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, operators

I have been working with xslt recently, and I have been having trouble understanding the difference between | and or and when I should use which. I understand I can just use the error messages to figure out which one I need to be using but I am interested in learning why I can't use one or the other.

Would anyone be able to help point me in the right direction to someplace where I can learn the difference?

Answer (score 13):

`|` is concerned with nodes, `or` is concerned with "truth", that is, Boolean values.

### Explanation

**The `|` or `union` operator**

This operator returns the *union* of two sequences that, in this case, are interpreted as two sets of nodes. An interesting detail is that the union operator removes any duplicate nodes. Also, it only accepts operands of the type `node()*`, i.e. a sequence of nodes. The nodes are returned in document order.

**The `or` operator**

The technical term for this operator is *Boolean Disjunction*. It takes two arguments, both of which must evaluate to a Boolean value ("true" or "false") individually. Or, more precisely, the operands of `or` are jugded by their *effective Boolean value* by converting them to `xs:boolean`. All of this also applies to the `and` operator, by the way.

### Examples

Use the `union` operator to enlarge a set of nodes, typically in a template match:

```
<xsl:template match="Root|Jon">
```

Why not use the `or` operator here? Because the `match` attribute expects a set of nodes as its value. `union` returns a set of nodes, whereas the `or` operator returns a Boolean value. You cannot define a template match for a Boolean.

---

Use the `or` operator to implement *alternatives* in XSLT code, mainly using `xsl:if` or `xsl:choose`:

```
<xsl:if test="$var lt 354 or $var gt 5647">
```

If any of the two operands of this `or` operation evaluates to `true`, then the content of `xsl:if` will be evaluated, too. But not only comparisons like "less than" (`lt`) have a Boolean value, the following is also perfectly legal:

```
<xsl:if test="$var1 or $var2">
```

The above expression only evaluates to `true` if at least one of the two variables is a non-empty sequence. This is because an empty sequence is defined to have the effective Boolean value of `false`.

---

### Coercion

Note that because of the way XSLT coerces things to appropriate types, there are some contexts where either operator can be used.  Consider these two conditionals:

```
<xsl:if test="Root | Jon"> ... <xsl:if>

<xsl:if test="Root or Jon"> ... <xsl:if>
```

The first conditional tests whether the union of the set of children named `Root` and the set of children named `Jon` is non-empty.  The expression `Root | Jon` returns a sequence of nodes, and then that sequence is coerced to a boolean value because `if` requires a boolean value; if the sequence is non-empty, the effective boolean value is true.

The second conditional tests whether either of the two sets of children (children named `Root` and children named `Jon`) is non-empty.  The expression `Root or Jon` returns a boolean value, and since the operator `or` requires boolean arguments, the two sets are each coerced to boolean, and then the `or` operator is applied.

The outcome is the same, but (as you can see) the two expressions reach that outcome in subtly different ways.

Comment: @C.M.Sperberg-McQueen Thanks for the addition on coercion! My answer definitely lacked this information.

Answer (score 1):

From **Documentation**

`|` - The union operator. For example, the match attribute in the element `<xsl:template match="a|b">` matches all `<a>` and `<b>` elements

`or` - Tests whether either the first or second expressions are `true`. If the first expression is `true`, the second is not evaluated.