# What does this '|' mean in node()|@*

Tags: xslt

I wish to know what is the purpose of `"|"` in `node()|@*`..
I know that `node()` means all child of current node and `@*` means all attributes for the context nodes,but I don'nt understand why that 'or' symbol (as in any programming language) is there??

What purpose does it serves??

Comment: Not trying to promote my own answer, but I think I have answered this question already: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25407704/1987598.

Comment: Thanks @MathiasMüller and Sorry the answer didn't came during search cause I didn't used the right serach keywords.

Comment: No worries - if you still have any doubts after reading it, comment there - or here and I'm glad to answer.