# How do I reuse an id found by a template match?

Tags: xslt

How do I use the result of a search inside another template?
Suppose this:

```
 <parent>
    <test>
        <bla Id="1">
            <mychild attr="x" />
        </bla>
        <bla Id="2">
            <mychild attr="y" />
        </bla>
        <bla Id="3">
            <mychild attr="z" />
        </bla>
    </test>

    <test2>
        <bla2 Id="1" />
        <bla2 Id="2" />
        <bla2 Id="3" />
    </test2>
</parent>
```

I want to first find out which bla has a child with attr="x", save that bla's Id and then delete every `<bla2>` that has that Id as well as the `<bla>` itself.
So far I have this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:wix="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
 <xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="parent/test/bla">
  <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="mychild[@attr='x']">
            <!-- apparently I cannot reuse this.. -->
            <xsl:variable name="idToDelete"><xsl:value-of select="@Id"/></xsl:variable>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It works fine for deleting the first `<bla>`, but now I'm stuck on how to reuse the Id to delete the `bla2` items with that id in another template match/search.
I tried xsl:variable (they go out of scope apparently..) I tried call-template with with-param.. for some reason that didnt delete the item in the first match anymore and the 2nd template didnt work either.
How do I solve this problem the XSLT™ way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:variable name="id-to-delete">
    <xsl:value-of select="/parent/test/bla[mychild/@attr = 'x']/@Id"/>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="bla | bla2">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="@Id = $id-to-delete"/>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: can you explain the need for the select= in apply-templates? When I read the docs on it, they all say that the default apply-templates would take the current node anyway.. and why is there a need for an OR clause there

Comment: @Blub the `@select` in `apply-templates` pushes all the context node's attributes and all of its child nodes for processing(which will be processed by the first template(identity transform template). If I didn't have the select attribute, the attributes won't be copied. By the way, `|` is the union operator and not `or`.

Comment: Exactly, those operators are [definitely not the same](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25407704/1987598).

Comment: IMHO, you should make your last template `match="bla | bla2"` instead of `match="*[starts-with(name(), 'bla')]"`. There's no reason to suppose that the similarity in names is anything but a coincidence. And there could well be yet another element that starts with 'bla' but has nothing to do with the issue at hand.

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest looking at it from the opposite direction:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="bla" match="bla" use="@Id" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="bla[mychild/@attr='x']"/>
<xsl:template match="bla2[key('bla', @Id)/mychild/@attr='x']" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

IOW, delete any `bla` that has a `mychild` with attr="x", then delete any `bla2` that has a `bla` with the same Id whose `mychild` has attr="x".

---

### Edit:

If you prefer, you could make this even more efficient by telling the key to index only the nodes of interest:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="deleted-bla" match="bla[mychild/@attr='x']" use="@Id" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="bla[key('deleted-bla', @Id)]"/>
<xsl:template match="bla2[key('deleted-bla', @Id)]" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: that seems like a very consise way to do it, wow, I havent used the xsl:key successfully before, I have to try this myself

Comment: Nice usage of key, +1.