# XPath: How to select all elements which have one attribute or another

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I've been searching everywhere for this and can't find a solution to my problem. I'm trying to find an XPath expression that will select all elements with an attribute named "user" or "product" (or both). I know the XPath expression for one attribute would be :

```
//*[@user]
```

or

```
//*[@product]
```

And these both work fine, they grab all elements with the proper attribute anywhere inside the document. But whenever I try to combine them :

```
//*[@user|@product]
```

or

```
//*[@user]|//*[@product]
```

I only get the elements found in the first level where these attributes are found. Here's an example of my XML document :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="xslt.xml" type="application/xml"?>
<catalog>
<item user="me" product="coffee" />
<price product="expensive" quality="good">$19.50</price>
<item user="still me"><note product="poison">Do not eat.</note></item>
<price product="mystery"><exchange user="still me" product="euro" />$99.95</price>
</catalog>
```

Now with this XSLT transformation :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="//*[@user|@product]">
<xsl:copy />
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I only get these elements :

```
<item/>
<price/>
<item/>
<price/>
```

But what I really want is this :

```
<item/>
<price/>
<item/>
<note/>
<price/>
<exchange/>
```

Of course, as you might have guessed already, when I put the "user" attribute in my catalog element, all that's selected is the catalog element, no children.

I've been trying for hours and can't find the solution. If anyone knows how to fix this, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though the answer provided by **Jiří Kantor** is right, you would have to use the following XSLT to get the desired result:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//*[@user or @product]"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Yes... I realized afterwards that my problem wasn't with the XPath expression but with the XSLT itself... I've been thrown off by the fact that the expression using only one attribute was working fine and not the combined one... tried to come and erase the question before someone read it and thought I was an idiot, but I'm too late :P

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I used another function to achieve my goal (xsl:for-each), but yours is simpler, I prefer yours.

Comment: Noone should ever feel like an idiot for asking a question :-)

Answer (score 3):

Use `or` instead of `|`. `|` is a different operator which I frankly do not know the meaning of :-)

Comment: `|` ~ Set operation; returns the union of two sets of nodes

Comment: [You can refer to this good answer by Mathias Müller to know the difference between `or` and `|` operators](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25407704/3244046).