# How to specify xpath to get data from parent and child with condition?

Tags: html, xpath

I want to extract link of an image but only in case if this picture does not contain word "thumb" in its name.

```
<a title="" rev="http://insales.ru/images/ large.jpeg"  href="http://insales.ru/images/T001.jpeg" class="TestClass">
    <img src="http://insales.ru/images/thumb.jpeg" class="productimage">
</a>
```

So I want to extract "http://insales.ru/images/thumb.jpeg" line from `<img>` tag if only picture name does not have "thumb" keyword.

I am trying to do like that:

```
//a[@class='TestClass']//img[not(contains(@src, 'thumb'))]
```

Not working. Because I am loosing data from `<a>` now.

Sometimes I extract links directly from `<a>` tag. From rev or href. But sometimes from `<img>` child of `<a>`.

How to specify xpath that will allow to extract links from parent or its child. But there is a condition for child.

**In details:**

I am parsing data from online store. To be specific I am trying to get images of a product. The code I provided represents one image of a product. I need only big version of picture. Not small thumbnail picture. The problem is that sometimes link to big picture presented in rev attribute of `<a>` tag. Sometimes it is presented in src attribute of `<img>` tag.

**Case 1 (link I need presented in `<a>` tag and rev attribute**

```
    <li class='product-item'>
      <a title="" rev="http://insales.ru/images/ large.jpeg"    href="http://insales.ru/images/T001.jpeg" class="MagicThumb-swap">
          <img src="http://insales.ru/images/thumb_T001" class="productimage" title=" Tissot">
      </a>
    </li>
```

In that case I need to extract **http://insales.ru/images/large.jpeg** line. I dont need http://insales.ru/images/thumb_T001 that is in `<img>` tag.

**Case 2 (link I need presented in `<img>` tag and src attribute)**

```
<div class='item'>
      <a title="" id="Zoomer" class="MagicZoomPlus jqzoom modal" href="http:// insales.ru/images/thumbi14.jpg" >
         <img src="http://insales.ru/images/large_i14.jpg" title="Orient” class="productimage">
      </a>
</div>
```

In this second case I need to extract **http://insales.ru/images/large_i14.jpg** line. And I dont need http:// insales.ru/images/thumbi14.jpg that is in `<a>` tag.

I know how to extract link in each of these two cases. But I don’t know how to make universal xpath that will allow getting links to big pictures in both scenarios. Thata why i am trying to make a condition based on picture name in link. If there is a 'thumb' keyword in link im trying to filter it out.

Comment: What piece of HTML would you like to get from an `a` element? Please show a larger sample of HTML, with all possible scenarios present: a case where something should be selected from the `a` element directly, a case where the `source` attribute of the `img` element should be selected, a case where `img/@source` should not be selected, and a case where nothing from `a` should be selected (if there is such a case). And show the _exact_ output you'd like to get from that larger sample.

Comment: I made more specific description of what I am trying to do. After in details word in my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have understood correctly now, the correct path expression is

```
//a/@rev[not(contains(.,'thumb'))] | //img/@src[not(contains(.,'thumb'))]
```

where `|` is the [`union` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25407704/1987598) that combines sets of nodes.

Assuming an input document like

```
<html>
<li class='product-item'>
    <a title="" rev="http://insales.ru/images/ large.jpeg"    href="http://insales.ru/images/T001.jpeg" class="MagicThumb-swap">
          <img src="http://insales.ru/images/thumb_T001" class="productimage" title=" Tissot"/>
    </a>
</li>
<div class='item'>
      <a title="" id="Zoomer" class="MagicZoomPlus jqzoom modal" href="http:// insales.ru/images/thumbi14.jpg" >
         <img src="http://insales.ru/images/large_i14.jpg" title="Orient" class="productimage"/>
      </a>
</div>
</html>
```

the result will be (individual results separated by `-----------`):

```
rev="http://insales.ru/images/ large.jpeg"
-----------------------
src="http://insales.ru/images/large_i14.jpg"
```

And in case you need to include the `class` attribute of `a`:

```
//a[@class='TestClass']/@rev[not(contains(.,'thumb'))] | //a[@class='TestClass']/img/@src[not(contains(.,'thumb'))]
```

However, you did not mention that in your "detailed" description.