# How to select text in a node whether or not inside another tag

Tags: html, ruby, xpath

I am trying to write an xpath selector that extracts names that may or may not be inside `span`, i.e., from both the fragments below:

```
<p class='out'>
<span>John</span>
</p>

<p class='out'>
Alice
</p>

<p class='out'>
<span>Tim</span>
</p>

<p class='out'>
Doe
</p>

<p class='out'>
<span>Tina</span>
</p>

<p class='out'>
Joseph
</p>
```

I was able to write for individual cases, but how do I do it for both?

This was my attempt:

`//p/span/text()`

Comment: We'd like to see your attempted XPath. Asking but not showing your attempt makes it look like you want us to write it for you, not help you fix your work. It also results in us shooting in the dark, trying to guess what you know and haven't tried, resulting in broad answers to a broad question. Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]".

Comment: @theTinMan didn't include it as it was very simple. Don't know Xpath enough search to get what I am looking for, thats why posted this. Possibly this may be very simple.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/128421. I'd also recommend you read http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints and the linked http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html. We expect you to spend time trying to figure things out; That's a strong characteristic of a developer. Once you have tried MANY times, then try more, then write a question following the guidelines in those pages.

Comment: Does `<p class='out'>` always exist? If so, then use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use OR -> `|` operator to achieve your requirement

Try something like below:-

```
 //p[not(self::span)] | /span
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: I want to select generic name; not just Alice.

Comment: can you share more HTML code or xpath which is working for you individually

Comment: Just added more HTML; I need an xpath selector that can select all names.

Comment: [`or` is not the same as `|`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25407704/1987598). `p[not(self::span)]` does not make any sense, and `/span` will only find a `span` element if it is the outermost element - which it never is in HTML douments, because there `html` is the outermost element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like below, its not pure XPath solution as I have applied some processing on result:

```
XPath.each(xmldoc, "//p/span/text()|//p/text()").map(&:to_s).map(&:strip).reject(&:empty?)
```

---

Additional processing can be avoided if new lines can be removed from input

```
xmldoc = Document.new(html.split("\n").join)
XPath.match(xmldoc, "//p/span/text()|//p/text()")
```

---

Working sample shown below:

```
require 'rexml/document'
include REXML

html = <<-eos
<html>

<p class='out'>
<span>John</span>
</p>

<p class='out'>
Alice
</p>

<p class='out'>
<span>Tim</span>
</p>

<p class='out'>
Doe
</p>

<p class='out'>
<span>Tina</span>
</p>

<p class='out'>
Joseph
</p>

</html>
eos

xmldoc = Document.new(html)
XPath.each(xmldoc, "//p/span/text()|//p/text()").map(&:to_s).map(&:strip).reject(&:empty?)
#=> ["John", "Tim", "Tina", "Alice", "Doe", "Joseph"]
```

Comment: Thanks but is it possible to get the text without further operation using Ruby?

Comment: It may be, but after an hour of research - I could not figure it out.  The additional processing was needed because of new lines `\n` in the `text()` values - if you can ensure no `\n` in input, then, may be additional processing will not be needed.

Answer (score 0):

If `span` doesn't always exist, then don't use it as a way-marker.

I'd use something like:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<p class='out'>
<span>John</span>
</p>

<p class='out'>
Alice
</p>
EOT

doc.search('p.out').map(&:text)
# => ["\nJohn\n", "\nAlice\n"]
```

If it absolutely has to be XPath then use:

```
doc.search('//p[@class="out"]').map(&:text)
# => ["\nJohn\n", "\nAlice\n"]
```

I don't use XPath unless I have to. CSS results in more readable selectors most of the time, and readability leads to reduced maintenance.

How that works is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Thanks! Its a very good pointer, but the reason I _had_ to use xpath is because I am extracting values from an HTML table.